# Prove area of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle, two sides a, b are not equal. angle $\alpha$ is opposite to side $a$, angle $\beta$ is opposite to side $b$.

I need to prove the area of that triangle is $$\frac{{a}^{2}-{b}^{2}}{2\cdot (\cot{\beta}-\cot{\alpha})}$$
Can you give me a hint for how to start?

Comment: You can start by making a distinction between the three different types of triangles, and then drawing a line from the point where $a$ and $b$ intersect, perpendicular to the third line.

Comment: The best place to start is always by drawing diagrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ be the third side. Prove the following ($A$ denotes the area of the triangle):
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-4A\cot\alpha\tag{1} $$
The same result about $b$ is
$$b^2=a^2+c^2-4A\cot\beta\tag{2} $$
Then subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$. To prove this, use the law of cosines and the formula
$$A=\frac{bc\sin\alpha}{2} $$